# Update (new) password for iCloud account

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id

Today I decided to change the password of my iCloud account. I did so from the browser of my Mac. Then I thought I had to update it also on all my devices but surprisingly I did not have to. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior and helps illustrate how things work technically behind the scenes a bit.

When you enter your AppleID or password, Apple generally never stores that and instead makes a secure token derived from elements including your password that then is stored and identifies that specific device to the servers that provide sync or services.

When you change your password, that prompts (optionally) to renew that cookie or certificate but doesn’t stop syncing of data just because a routine password change has arrived.

This lets Apple minimize risk and disruption when you ask to update your password versus having a more urgent need to tie all the devices together and break / deny service when a lock out or forced change is happening.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you change the Password of your [AppleID](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) - do you think so?

Apple never Share passwords to other devices and never have access to this. 
Your AppleID password is synonymous with your iCloud. If you change your AppleID Password this will encrypt your iCloud with your new Password.

To access in your iCloud with your devices:

1. Log out from iCloud of all your devices
2. Log in with your new Password.

For the next Time if you need to change your password this is the right way:

1. Log out from your iCloud in all your devices
2. Access your Browser to your [AppleID](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) and change the Password.
3. Log in with your new Password to all your iCloud devices.
4. I would recommend to activate the [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)

Comment: Thanks. But how is iCloud able to sync then? If I add something to the calendar from iCloud.com, then I can see it on my iPhone.

Comment: Because your iCloud is  linked with your AppleID (E-Mail and Password). All syncs passes your AppleID to your iCloud Account. All devices that connected with them - automatically sync.

Comment: Sure but I still have the old password on all my devices!

Comment: Is it still work your devices with your old password?

Comment: Exactly! I did not touch them.

Comment: I can't believe it. Have you set the new password in your AppleID devices?

Comment: I just changed it from the browser of my Mac (Apple website) and then I tried to add a Calendar event from iCloud.com (signed in with the new password of course). It appeared on ALL my devices which I did NOT touch: I did not signed out and in with the new password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65516/discussion-between-dante12-and-sensitive-scientist).